# Should the bittorrent tag handle the app or the protocol?

Tags: discussion

Should we handle the [bittorrent](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent) tag as a tag for the app itself, or as a synonym for [torrents](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torrents) (which, in my opinion, should be [torrent](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torrent))?

Comment: Just to add to this, the protocol is also called "BitTorrent" and the [Wikipedia page for BitTorrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent) is for the protocol, not the product or company.

Comment: @GAThrawn Aaah, that is quite confusing. The author of the bittorrent protocol also named his bittorrent client as bittorrent.

Comment: However, based on usage among regular users, I think more would consider torrent to be the protocol, and bittorrent as the app. I suppose we can live with this assumption. @GAThrawn

Comment: There's an implied follow-up here, which no one has addressed: if we say [tag:bittorrent] is about the protocol, and is pretty much a synonym for [tag:torrents], then what do we call the tag relating to the app?

Comment: @DanHulme [tag:bittorrent] for the protocol, [tag:bittorrent-app] for the app?

Answer (score 2):

*Torrent* would rather refer to the file (see [Torrent file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file)), and thus again would be confusing. Moreover, this is the context this word is most commonly used, IMHO (if one "downloads a torrent", he's not downloading a protocol).

Checking [Wikipedia on "torrent"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent) doesn't mention "torrent" as protocol, only "BitTorrent" (*a peer-to-peer file sharing (P2P) communications protocol*).

Conclusion: [bittorrent](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent) clearly refers to the *protocol*, though an application by the same name does exist.

Answer (score 0):

[bittorrent](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent) clearly refers to the application, as a Google search result will show.

And yes, I agree that [torrent](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torrent) is preferable over [torrents](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torrents). But I don't agree that a protocol should be a synonym of the application, because there are several other applications that can handle torrents as well.